# add participants to google calendar through php api?

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

i dont seem to be able to figure out how to add participants (guests) to an event through the php api?

is it not possibly?
any workaround perhaps?

any code snippets would be of great help, couldnt find anything by googling (just the same examples from the documentation where they have no participants....)

Comment: You should look at CalDAV and the iCalendar format. http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/caldav/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it; one need to set a SendEventNotifications on the event, like this:

```
$notification = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar_Extension_SendEventNotifications(); 
$notification->setValue(true); 
$event->SendEventNotifications = $notification;
```